Vee-validate custom rule translation
i am Vee-valdiate 4 with vue3,
i am trying to use load the translation for the defined custom rules and mix them with loaded translation from @vee-validate/i18n, i couldn't find it in the docs,
customRulesTranslation.js:
    import { localize } from '@vee-validate/i18n';

    localize({
      en: {
        messages: {
      PASSED: 'The passwords do not match',
    },
     },
    de: {
    messages: {
      PASSED: 'Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein',
    },
  },

customRules.js:
    defineRule('PASSED', (value) => {
  // Check if password field is empty
  if (!value) {
    return false;
  }
  // Check if value matches the email pattern and does not contain forbidden characters
  if (!/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/.test(value)) {
    return 'The password field should contain at least a Number, a Special Character and an Uppercase Letter';
  }
  return true;
});

and i have this veevalidateInit:
import { localize, setLocale } from '@vee-validate/i18n';
import { configure } from 'vee-validate';
import './veeValidateCustomRulesTranslation';

export default {
  methods: {
    async setValidationTranslation(lang) {
      const loadedTranslation = await import(`@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/${lang}.json`);

      setLocale(lang);
      configure({
        generateMessage: localize({
          [lang]: loadedTranslation,
        }),
      });
    },
  },
};

i am trying to find a way to mix the loaded translation with the defined rules translation
